# History and completion not working in coffeescript repl on linux mint

Tags: terminal, linux-mint, history, autocomplete, coffeescript

I have recently switched from Ubuntu 12.04 to Linux Mint 14. One thing that is mysteriously not working is autocompletion (tab) and history (uparrow) in coffeescript repl (`coffee` command). Instead of completing it puts literal tab and instead of showing previous statements it puts `^[[A`. Happens in every kind of terminal ie. guake, gnome-terminal and text terminal. The same in `node` repl works as intended. I did some googling but without success.

Where should I start troubleshooting?

Comment: Well, I can answer this myself now, but SE won't let me do it for next seven hours :P I'll post my answer later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I did some more googling :)

In short:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js-libs
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:chris-lea/libjs-underscore
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

This will upgrade your coffeescript to latest version (which is 1.4 now). I assume you already use latest node.js from `ppa:chris-lea/node.js`

It seems there was an issue with coffeescript 1.3.* and node 0.8.*.

Background info

- https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/2399, and search for coffeescript 1.4 ppa led to
- http://twitter.com/justinfreitag/statuses/271734729928220672 - very informative.

Hope that will help someone :)